# "this is/was the first thing that I noticed/notice": which one is correct?

Tags: meaning

Which of the sentences is grammatically and meaningfully correct?

> This was the first thing that I noticed

or

> This is the first thing that I noticed

or

> This was the first thing that I notice

What is the difference between the first and the third sentence in terms of meaning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is a difference of tense.

"Noticed" is past tense.  "Notice" is present tense.

If you are describing your thoughts in the past:

> I opened the door and the first thing I noticed was the box in the middle or the room.

This is a simple past tense narrative. The speaker is telling a story about something that happened in the past.

You use the present tense when describing your current and immediate thoughts, as you are thinking them.

> (on phone) Hi John, I've got your email in front of me and I notice that you haven't included the date of the festival.

This is sometimes called "commentary"  You also use notice in other present tense situations

> Everyday I notice the sun rising earlier.
>
> People notice what is in front of them more than what is behind them.

Comment: Hello! What if we're writing an email about something that I noticed an hour ago and it still holds true? WOuld I still use "I notice?" Example: I notice you removed the column from the file.

Comment: This is possible.  It's a bit of a lie (you are saying that you notice the fact as you are writing the email, you are suggesting that you have the spreadsheet open as you are writing) but you might do that to give a sense of immediacy and "presence" to the email.  It is a stylistic matter to use present tense. You could use past tense correctly since the act of noticing the change happened an hour ago.